# Mockito running in java 8 but giving unfinished stubbing error in java 11

Tags: java, mockito

I am using mockito to mock some methods while writing unit tests. It is working fine in java 8, but when i use java 11 it gives these errors :

- java.lang.IllegalStateException: message == null
- org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedStubbingException:
  Unfinished stubbing detected here:

This is the mockito dependency i am using :

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
  <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
  <version>1.10.19</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

This is the sample unit test :

```
public class ClientTest {

private OtherClient otherClient;

@Mock
private OkHttpClient client;

@Mock
private Call call;

@Before
public void setUp() throws IOException {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    otherClient = new OtherClient(client, new ObjectMapper(), "http://localhost:8080");
    Mockito.when(client.newCall(Mockito.any())).thenReturn(call);
}

@Test
public void testUploadSuccess() throws IOException {

    Response.Builder builder = new Response.Builder();
    builder.code(200);
    builder.request(new Request.Builder().url("http://localhost:8080").build());
    builder.protocol(Protocol.HTTP_1_1);
    builder.body(ResponseBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/json"), "{}"));
    Mockito.when(call.execute()).thenReturn(builder.build());
    File temp = File.createTempFile("upload", "test.pdf");
    try {
        otherClient.upload("test", temp,
                FileUploadRequest.builder().build(),
                ImmutableMap.of("Authorization", ""));
    } catch (UploadException e) {
        Assert.fail("Failed to Upload");
    } finally {
        FileUtils.deleteQuietly(temp);
    }
}
}
```

Please help.

Comment: Please show a [mcve].

Comment: Hi, I have added minimal reproducible code

Comment: Is `Mockito.doReturn(builder.build()).when(call).execute()` working for you?

Comment: No, I tried that already but getting same error.

Comment: What junit are you using?

Comment: junit version is 4.12

Comment: Try updating mockito. 1.10.19 was released in 2014, Java 11 in 2018.